# The program stops when the ObjectInputStream object is created

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream

I have two methods in server and in client:

Server:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 9998);
        System.out.println("connected");
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("1");
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        output.writeObject(new Message(CONFIG, "ping"));

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/window/fxmls/window.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        AnchorPane anchorPane = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Client:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9998);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("connected");
                input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(1);
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                Message message = (Message) input.readObject();
                if (message.getHeader() == CONFIG && message.getMessage().equals("ping")) {
                    System.out.println(message.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When client is start running, sends checking message `"ping`" using ObjecInputStream, but code in above methods is stopping on `System.out.println(1);` I don't know why. Before in similar code all was running. What I did bad? `input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` is waiting for something what I haven't done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have a deadlock here. If you start the server first, it will start listening for connections on port 9998. When you then start the client, it makes a connection to the server. The server accepts the connection, and tries to create an `ObjectInputStream`. The `ObjectInputStream` constructor (and the server thread) will block until it can read a stream header from the client (which the client hasn't sent yet). So the server doesn't get to the point where it creates an `ObjectOutputStream` (which would cause data to be sent to the client).

Meanwhile the client is attempting to create an `ObjectInputStream` and will block because the server hasn't yet sent any data. The result is two threads blocked in the `ObjectInputStream` constructor.

The solution is quite simple - in the server, create the `ObjectOutputStream` first, then create the `ObjectInputStream`:

```
socket = new Socket("localhost", 9998);
output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I have done how you sayed, but `output.writeObject(new Message(CONFIG, "ping"));` is doing error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: You should probably create a new question for that.